# TypeScript: How to automatically change the optional value of a type based on an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
interface Song {
  songTitle: string;
  singer: string;
  album: string;
  duration: string;
  id: string;
  imgUrl?: string,
  operation?: string 
}
type SongFiled = 'songTitle' | 'singer' | 'album' | 'duration' | 'id' | 'imgUrl'|'operation';

interface Column {
  prop: SongFiled;
  title: string;
  flex: string; 
  isA?: boolean;
}
```

I want the optional values of type to be automatically changed based on the interface instead of adding one by one

Comment: `type SongFiled = keyof Song;`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your column objects in that way:

```js
const generateColumns = (song: Song): Column[] => {
  const songEntries = Object.entries(song);
  const columns: Column = songEntries.map(([ songKey, songValue ]: [ SongFiled, string ]) => ({
    prop: songKey,
    title: songValue,
  }));
  return columns; 
}
```